# Custom DataType generators with Feed4J/benerator

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am trying to implement a custom DataType generator for use with [Feed4JUnit](http://databene.org/feed4junit.html). I have tried implementing the provided `Generator` interface. But now I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.databene.feed4junit.generators.CustomCheckGenerator$1 cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

My implementation can be found here: http://goo.gl/EALMu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with the help of the tool developers.

> `JUnit` is designed to calculate each test invocation in advance. If you
>   do not limit the amount of generated test data, you will run into
>   `OutOfMemoryError`.
>
> You can alternatively use an @InvocationCount:
>
> ```
> @Test
> @InvocationCount(100)
> public void testAdd(int param1, int param2) {
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> or limit the amount of data in the Generator code, by return null in
>   `generate()`.

Solution was posted [here](http://databene.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=357&p=1242#p1241).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to cast an Enum to something else.
Can't be of more help than that I'm afraid, as I don't know the specific tool, but look in that direction.